# Derivative of $10^x\cdot\log_{10}(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Derive  $10^x\cdot\log_{10}(x)$

$$10^x\cdot \ln(10)\cdot \log_{10}(x)+\frac{1}{x\cdot \ln(10)}\cdot 10^x$$

But [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derive%2010%5Exlogx&a=*FunClash.log-_*Log10-) gives another solution. Where am I wrong?

Comment: did you get the answer from W|A?

Comment: @Alex No, it is not the same

Comment: It's correct, just in different forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\text{your answer} & = 10^x\cdot \ln10\cdot \log_{10} x+\frac{1}{x\cdot \ln10}\cdot 10^x \\[10pt]
& = 10^x \ln x + \frac{10^x}{x\ln 10} \\[10pt]
& = 10^x \left( \ln x + \frac 1 {x\ln 10} \right) = \text{Wolfram's answer}.
\end{align}
Note that where Wolfram writes $\log x$ or $\log 10$ with no base specified, it means the base is $e$, so it's the natural logarithm.

Note also that we used the identity $\ln10\cdot\log_{10}x = \ln x$.  That is an instance of the change-of-base formula for logarithms.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is correct, but you can simplify it further using the change of base formula. Where $\log x$ is in base $10$ and $\ln x$ is the natural log, you have

$$10^x\cdot \ln10\cdot \log x+\frac{1}{x\cdot \ln10}\cdot 10^x$$

$$=10^x\cdot \left(\ln10\cdot \color{green}{\log x}+\frac{1}{x\cdot \ln 10}\right)$$

$$=10^x\cdot \left(\ln10\cdot \color{green}{\frac{\ln x}{\ln 10}}+\frac{1}{x\cdot \ln 10}\right)$$

$$=10^x\cdot \left(\ln x+\frac{1}{x\cdot \ln 10}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. You may use
$$
(u \times v)'=u'v+uv'
$$ in the form
$$
\left(10^x\log_{10}(x)\right)'=\left(e^{x \ln 10} \times \frac{ \ln x}{\ln 10}\right)'.
$$ Can you take it from there?

Comment: what is $\frac{lnx}{ln10}$?

Comment: It is just the definition of $\log_{10} (x)$.

Comment: I am trying to find my mistake, the first part $u'v$ is $10^x\cdot \ln(10)\cdot \log_{10}(x)$ but there is where wolfram says I have a problem

Comment: This is equal to $10^x \: \ln x$. Do you  see why?

Answer (score 1):

Use the facts

> $$(a^x)' = a^x \ln a, \quad (\log_a(x))' = \frac{1}{x\ln a}$$
>   for $a > 0$ and $a \neq 1$.

Then use the multiplication formula for differentiation to get
\begin{align}
& (10^x \log_{10}x)' \\
= & (10^x)'\log_{10}x + 10^x (\log_{10}x)' \\
= & 10^x \ln (10) \log_{10}x + 10^x \frac{1}{x\ln 10}.
\end{align}
If you want to express your final result in natural logs, then you can simplify by writing 
$$\log_{10}x = \frac{\ln x}{\ln 10},$$
in this way the answer would agree with the wolfram output exactly.

Comment: That what I answered

Answer (score 1):

Using 
$$\log_{10}(x) = \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(10)}$$
then 
\begin{align}
D \left[ 10^{x} \, \log_{10}(x) \right] &= D \left[ e^{x \, \ln(10)} \, \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(10)} \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{\ln(10)} \, \left[ \frac{10^{x}}{x} + \ln(10) \, 10^{x} \, \ln(x) \right] \\
&= 10^{x} \, \left[ \frac{1}{ x \, \ln(10)} + \ln(10) \, \log_{10}(x) \right]
\end{align}

Comment: So I am right, it is just the Wolfram canceled out $ln(10)$ using the log representation

Comment: @gbox Yes, Michael Hardy demonstrates this in his responce

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac {\Bbb d} {\Bbb dx} [10x \dfrac {\ln x} {\ln 10}] =\dfrac {\frac {\Bbb d} {\Bbb dx} (10x \ln x)} {\ln 10} = \dfrac {\frac {\Bbb d} {\Bbb dx} [10^x] \ln x + 10^x \frac {\Bbb d} {\Bbb dx} \ln x} {\ln 10} = \dfrac {\ln 10 10^x \ln x + \frac 1 x 10^x} {\ln 10} = \dfrac {\ln 10 10^x \ln x + \frac {10^x} x} {\ln 10}$$

Comment: Hi - your answer is difficult to read... You might take a look at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(10^x\cdot\log_{10}(x)\right)=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{10^x\ln(x)}{\ln(10)}\right)=$$
$$\frac{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(10^x\ln(x)\right)}{\ln(10)}=\frac{\ln(x)\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}(10^x)+10^x\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}(\ln(x))}{\ln(10)}=$$
$$\frac{10^x\ln(10)\ln(x)+10^x\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}(\ln(x))}{\ln(10)}=\frac{10^x\ln(10)\ln(x)+\frac{10^x}{x}}{\ln(10)}=$$
$$10^x\left(\ln(x)+\frac{1}{x\ln(10)}\right)$$